# "bundle install" failure and rails rubies and rvm messed up

Tags: ruby, segmentation-fault, rvm, bundle

I messed up with my rails and rubies and rvm and I have already reinstall them for a few times. To reinstall I do

```
rvm implode
```

I install everything with sudo

I can't create any new rails projects right now and it stopped when installing bundle and keep giving the Segmentation fault.

here is the error I have when doing bundle install in a app that I created before

```
trample1210$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/./Users/trample1210/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]
```

Comment: Why are you installing everything with `sudo`? You shouldn't use `sudo` at all with RVM unless you know exactly why.

Comment: If I don't use sudo it says permission denied when I install gems

Comment: Then you installed RVM wrong—possibly with `sudo`. Unless you're doing a server/"multi-user" install, you should *never* use `sudo` with RVM. Even then to quote the [RVM site](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/): "If you need to use `sudo` or `rvmsudo` after the install is complete, some part of the install directions were not properly followed."

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in rubies compiled with `clang` you need to reinstall your ruby with GNU GCC, easiest way to get it is to install osx-gcc-installer.

To reinstall ruby run:

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

There is no need to implode, more important is to get proper compiler - `gcc-4.2` should output no **clang** or **LLVM**.

Comment: Worked for me! There is a lot of misinfo even on SO that clang works - IT DOESN'T! Bundle fails!